# What are the names of the types of animations on this GIF?

Tags: user-interface, user-experience

What are the names of the types of animations on this GIF?
https://miro.medium.com/max/1400/1*EnfbAvsPg7d1OTorXugvmQ.gif

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found [several](https://www.flinto.com/learn/create-a-full-screen-transition) [examples](https://codemyui.com/ecommerce-grid-full-screen-product-click/) and most of them use the terminology **“full-screen transition”** to describe this effect.